# existing bash script for deleting old backup files - how does it work?

Tags: bash, shell, osx-yosemite

I'm a total beginner with scripts. I have some questings regarding an old script, which should delete old backup files.

```
KEEP_FULL=7
KEEP_DAILY=14
KEEP_WEEKLY=30

DB_FULL_PATH=/Volumes/path

LAST_DAY=0
LAST_WEEK=0
LAST_MONTH=0
find $DB_FULL_PATH -type f| while read f; do
    < <(stat -f %Sm -t "%m %V %d" $f) read -s MONTH WEEK DAY 
    if [ $DAY -eq $LAST_DAY ]; then
        find $f -mtime +$KEEP_FULL | xargs rm 
    else if [ $WEEK -eq $LAST_WEEK ]; then
        find $f -mtime +$KEEP_DAILY | xargs rm 
    else if [ $MONTH -eq $LAST_MONTH ]; then
        find $f -mtime +$KEEP_WEEKLY | xargs rm 
    fi fi fi
    export LAST_DAY=$DAY
    export LAST_WEEK=$WEEK
    export LAST_MONTH=$MONTH
done
```

Could someone explain (for dummies) what happens within the while-loop?
I understand that for each file within the folder the information (day, week, month of creation) is written into $MONTH $WEEK $DAY.
But the following logic I don't understand correctly.

Comment: @Amessihel OS Yosemite (10.10.5) runs with bash command; scriptname ist test.sh: (bash test.sh)

Comment: @Amessihel The script is supposed to delete old backup files and it worked fine for a long time (it is not from me). 
Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer won't be complete because I lack informations. Also It seems overly complex for the task it should do.*

---

The loop below process all files under /Volumes/path and stores them in the variable `f`.

```
find $DB_FULL_PATH -type f| while read f; do
    # [...]
done
```

For each file `f`, this command is first performed:

```
< <(stat -f %Sm -t "%m %V %d" $f) read -s MONTH WEEK DAY
```

1. `stat` is invoked on the file `f`

   - According to the [man page](https://ss64.com/osx/stat.html) of stat (OSX):

   > `-f` *format*  Display information using the specified format. See the FORMATS section for a description of valid formats.
   >
   > `-t` *timefmt*  Display timestamps using the specified format.  This format is passed directly to [strftime](https://ss64.com/osx/syntax-strftime.html)(3).

   - According to the **FORMATS** section of the manual page, `%Sm` is the combination of `S` and `m`, which stand respectively for 1) "the [last] time file was  [...] **modified**" (`m`) and 2) formatted, "if applicable, should be in string format" (`S`, it should be the case here).
   - According to the manual page of [strftime](https://ss64.com/osx/read.html), **`%m %V %d`** stand for the **month**, the **week number of the year** and the **day of the month** as a decimal number
2. The output is `read` and stored in variables `MONTH` `WEEK` and `DAY` (`-s` stands for [silent mode](https://ss64.com/osx/read.html))

At this point, you have the **month**, the **week number of the year** and the **day of the month** of the time the file was modifed.

Next the hardest part:

- If the day of modification of the previously processed file equals the current processed file one, then check if it was modified ([`-mtime`](https://ss64.com/osx/find.html)) one week ago (`KEEP_FULL`=7) ; if so, delete it (`f` is passed to `rm` with `xargs`):

  ```
  if [ $DAY -eq $LAST_DAY ]; then
      find $f -mtime +$KEEP_FULL | xargs rm 
  fi
  ```
- Otherwise, if the week number of the year of modification of the previously processed file (*breathes*) equals the current processed file one, then check if it was modified two weeks ago (`KEEP_DAILY`=14) ; if so, delete it:

  ```
    else if [ $WEEK -eq $LAST_WEEK ]; then
        find $f -mtime +$KEEP_DAILY | xargs rm
  ```
- Otherwise, if the month of modification of the previously processed file (*sips*) equals the current processed file one, then check if it was modified 30 days ago (`KEEP_WEEKLY`=30) ; if so, delete it:

  ```
    else if [ $MONTH -eq $LAST_MONTH ]; then
        find $f -mtime +$KEEP_WEEKLY | xargs rm 
    fi fi fi
  ```
- Retrieve the month, the week and the day of the month of the current file to process the next one with them (will be used as parts of the modification time of said "previously processed" file):

  ```
      export LAST_DAY=$DAY
      export LAST_WEEK=$WEEK
      export LAST_MONTH=$MONTH
  done
  ```

That said, to understand why such comparisons are performed, you need to know the order the first `find` outputs files injected to the standard input of the `while` loop.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much!!! The first find outputs the newest file.
You've said, the script seems overly complex for the task it should do. Do you know a better way? I will ask a new question regarding that matter.

Comment: You're welcome! It really depends on _how_ you want to keep or not backup files. I suggest you to make an attempt by yourself, and when you're stuck, asking specific questions, that is to say splitting your problem into smaller points. That way, effort will appear more obvious and you will be more likely to receive help. See also _[How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_ Good luck!